# Port Forwarding on Kali Linux (AWS)

Tags: linux

Hey everyone and good day

I set up a Linux Instance (Kali Linux) on AWS and i wanted to study and learn more about port forwarding hence i went for a free-tier on Amazon .

Now Issue is, when I set the inbound security Rules and what not and go to something like `http://canyouseeme.org` it returns that the PORT is closed except i have to use `netcat.`

Question is , How do i do port forwarding on kali Linux on AWS Please i would like to know.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What research have you done so far?

Comment: I have tried opening the security groups and making sure that port 4444 has been set open to incoming connections. then i used netcat, opened but its not consistent

Comment: These seem like pertinent things to include / edit into in the question. Are you simply trying to `nc` between two machines? Might be me, but I still don't have a clear idea of what you are trying to achieve or how you've gone about it.

Comment: No. i am trying to use Portforwarding. for LAN and WAN thats what i wonna do.

Comment: Welp, I've even more confused. I'm not sure how an AWS instance pertains to LAN port forwarding (WAN, maybe?). Regardless, I would still suggest you update your question to include what you have tried so far.